# Why isn't affected_rows working in this PHP Mysqli code?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a mysqli database object $DataBase and the following code works as intended:

```
    $stmt = $DataBase->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare("UPDATE `optshop_stock` SET quantity_b = ? WHERE product_id = ?;");
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $qty, $sku);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
```

But when I add:

```
echo $stmt->affected_rows;
```

**between** `$stmt->execute()` and `$stmt->close()` no value is echoed, not even a zero if nothing happened. Am I using this statement in a correct manner?

( I followed this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php example)

Comment: Think you should do: echo $Database->affected_rows;

Comment: you didn't follow the example "to a T".

Comment: Try adding this to the top of your script ~ `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. Given that you aren't getting any value shown, I'd say there's a good chance your query is failing

Comment: Exactly in between those two.

Comment: What do you mean @FunkFortyNiner ?

Comment: use the same example from the manual and replace the query with your own. On top of that, check for errors on the query and with error reporting for the php side of things.

Comment: @halojoy It works when I put that after the $stmt->close.

Comment: It is working now, but now I cannot see a difference with the code I posted above... It even gives the correct amount of affected rows if nothing has changed now... I will try to find out what happened and hope I did not waste everybody's' time..

Answer (score 1):

The property can be retrieved at database level (reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)):

```
echo $DataBase->affected_rows;
```

Comment: When I add it after $stmt-> close I get Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::affected_rows() in /usr/local/www/www.lemongrasshouse.ru/msk/includes/ajax.php on line 38

Comment: Yes now it does, when I add echo $DataBase->affected_rows; AFTER $stmt->close; it works, not before. 
This still makes me puzzled why $stmt->affected_rows; isn't working.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work, it now only returns 0 this way.

Comment: Did you rollback your server before testing again?

Comment: Actualy, $stmt->store_result(); is only for SELECT and not for INSERT, 
@TommasoBelluzzo UPDATE and DELETE.

Comment: Ah damn, that confused me... when we have somehow to stick on the original solution...

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo Yes I rollback each time. But even if I wouldn't, I should get a zero returned.

Answer (score -3):

I think  you should try to add $stmt->store_result() after $stmt->execute(), otherwise you can't get right results when use $stmt->affected_rows

Comment: Your answer looks very familiar ~ http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php#116595

Comment: This did not help me. It is also not in the example, but it does make sense to include.

Comment: It is incorrect, $stmt->store_result(); is only for SELECT, not for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE.